# Чтение массива из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Недавно начал изучать C++ и встретил такую задачу:

Файл input.txt

```
5 
7 
1 6 4 3 4 
4 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Не подскажите, как записать в 2 массива 5 элементов из 3-ей строки файла `input.txt` и 7 из 4-ой строки.

Comment: Формат исходных данных опишите подробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Завести массивы
2. Открыть файл
3. Пропустить строку
4. Пропустить строку
5. Читать цифры до конца строки в первый массив
6. Читать цифры до конца строки во второй массив
7. Закрыть файл

Для случая одной строки в файле:

```
in.open(f);

char z;
int i = 0;
while(!in.eof())
{
   in >> z;
   a[i++] = z - '0';
}

in.close(f);
```

Случай нескольких строк остается вам в качестве упражнения.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что ответ верный. Не учтено, что в данном примере кол-во элементов на строчках указано. По крайней мере, складывается такое ощущение. Но это вопрос формата исходных данных. Далее не рассмотрен вопрос работы с "резиновыми" массивами.